# Finding lines containing words that occur more than once using grep

Tags: bash, grep

How do I find all lines that contain duplicate lower case words.
I want to be able to do this using `egrep`, this is what I've tried thus far but I keep getting invalid back references:

```
egrep '\<(.)\>\1' inputFile.txt
egrep -w '\b(\w)\b\1' inputFile.txt
```

For example, if I have the following file:

```
The sky was grey. 
The fall term went on and on.
I hope every one has a very very happy holiday.
My heart is blue.
I like you too too too much
I love daisies.
```

It should find the following lines in the file:

```
The fall term went on and on.
I hope every one has a very very happy holiday.
I like you too too too much
```

It finds these lines because the words `on`, `very` and `too` occur more than once in each line.

Comment: Can you include a line from the file? And what the expected output from `egrep` should be?

Comment: I'd appreciate if someone could tell me why I'm still getting down votes, I revised the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be possible through `-E` or `-P` parameter.

```
grep -E '(\b[a-z]+\b).*\b\1\b' file
```

Example:

```
$ cat file
The fall term went on and on.
I hope every one has a very very happy holiday.
Hi foo bar.
$ grep -E '(\b[a-z]+\b).*\b\1\b' file
The fall term went on and on.
I hope every one has a very very happy holiday.
```

Comment: But one thing confuses me. Why do you put borders around the back reference?

Comment: see what happens when there is no word boundaries https://regex101.com/r/jR0bK9/1

Comment: the codes doesn't ignore the line when if it have triple or more words in the line. Bolboa wanted to print lines with exactly two words that are the same.

Comment: @Xorg where did he mentioned?

Comment: Under my answer
"Yeah, it does. But I want to know how to find the lines that contain a word that appears twice."

Answer (score 1):

Got it, you need find out duplicate words (all lowcase)

```
sed -n '/\s\([a-z]*\)\s.*\1/p' infile
```

### Tools are used to serve your request. To restrict on one tool is not good way.

`\1` is the feature in sed, but not sure if grep/egrep has this feature as well.

Comment: Actually its duplicate lower case words, as the examples I provided show. Plus, I need to do it with grep, and I just can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: So show as some samples file and your expect output.

Comment: I did... as I showed above, a line containing to words, such as :  have a _very_ _very_ happy holiday would show up as a result because very occurs twice in that line.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is about `grep`, but here is an `awk`
It would be more flexible, since you can easy change to counter `c`
`c==2` two equal words
`c>2` two or more equals words
etc

```
awk -F"[ \t.,]" '{c=0;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]++; for (i in a) c=c<a[i]?a[i]:c;delete a} c==2' file
The fall term went on and on.
I hope every one has a very very happy holiday.
```

It runs a loop trough all words in a line and create an array index for every words.
Then a new loop to see if there is word that is repeated.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
egrep '[a-z]*' my_file
```

this will find all lower case chars in each line

```
 egrep '[a-z]*' --color my_file
```

this will color the lower chars

Comment: grep is preferred if your are to find regular expression including words..you can use your code like 'grep '\<[a-z]*\>' and this will find all duplicates lower case letters. I suppose egrep is for extended regular expressions

Comment: Also if you use egrep "'[a-z]{2}". this will find all letters/characters duplicated in a word instead of the pattern being a whole word